# How read content of a span tag using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to scrap data from a link(site). There are many `p` tags, `header` and `span` tags in a site. I need to scrap data from a particular `span` tag.

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(URL);
foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("\\span"))
{
      string strData = node.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

I had tried by using keyword on parent tag which was not working for all kind of URLs.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE]". When you say "Please help me to fix it." we need to know how it's supposed to work and what it's doing wrong. Without that we can't fix a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?

You can start by fixing this:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("\\span"))
```

it should be:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"))
```

---

> But I want exact data. For example, there are too many span tags in source as `<span>abc</span>`, `<span>def</span>`, `<span>pqr</span>`, `<span>xyz</span>`. I want the result as "pqr". Is there any option to get it by count of particular tag or by index?

If you want to get, for example, the third span tag from the root:

```
 doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[3]")
```

If you want to get the node containing the text "pqr":

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(text(),'pqr')]");
```

You can use `SelectNodes` for the latter to get all span tags containing "pqr" in the text.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. I can get content. But I want exact data. For example, there are too many span tags in source as <span>abc</span>, <span>def</span>, <span>pqr</span>, <span>xyz</span>. I want the result as pqr. Is there any option to get it by count of particular tag or by index?

Comment: Still not sure what you want, @M-O, but I'll update my answer based on what I get from what you're saying

Comment: Inner text is dynamic. I will try first answer shared by you. @Tyress Thank you.

Comment: "What is the error?" Rather than answer a poorly asked question, flag it so it can be improved, then, once it has been, answer it. It's better to have a site with fewer well asked and answered questions, than one full of poorly asked questions and answers that guess what the problem was.